# error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu-server

I ran this command :

```
CREATE DATABASE wordpress;
```

And I got

> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

I ran the second command :

```
CREATE USER wordpressuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’;
```

And I got:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘password’' at line 1

What am I doing wrong? Running a freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 Server and trying to make a database for Wordpress.

Comment: You forget the single around username and localhost.

Comment: You mean like this : **CREATE USER 'wordpressuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’;** ??

Comment: You used the wrong quotes. Try this instead: `CREATE USER wordpressuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE USER 'wordpressuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Remember the quote in used is not around the @ symbol, and it is not ‘ ’ but ' '. And the first thing to do is to provide the user with access to the information this wordpressuser will need.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'wordpressuser'@'localhost';
```

The asterisks in this command refer to the database and table (respectively) that they can access—this specific command allows to the user to read, edit, execute and perform all tasks across all the databases and tables.

Once you have finalized the permissions that you want to set up for your new wordpressuser, always be sure to reload all the privileges.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Just here to say you're my hero. I found this at the end of 3 hours of searching down a laravel rabbithole. Besties!

Comment: Thank u so much.. I have different scenario but It helped me to step further in a moment of seconds.. Great thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below query

```
CREATE USER 'wordpressuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```